# How do I compute this abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

If $G = \bigoplus_i \mathbb{Z} / \langle w_i\rangle_i $ is a finitely generated abelian group and $w_i = \sum_j m_{ij} v_j$ such that $\{v_j\}_j$ is a basis for $\bigoplus_i \mathbb{Z}$, then $G = \mathbb{Z}^{n} \oplus(\bigoplus_i\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}) $, how do I compute the $n$ and the $p_i$'s ? 
 I know that there is a theorem saying that given a basis for an abelian group, say $\{v_j\}_j$, and a subgroup, then there exists a basis for this subgroup in the form $\{n_jv_j\}_j$, where $n_j \in \mathbb{Z}$, however how do I compute it?

I saw in a lecture that I could create a matrix $A =[m_{ij}]$ and then reduce it by operations with the columns and rows. I understand why the operation with rows is valid, however the operation with columns does not make sense, since it's not a linear combination of the $w_i$'s. However, of course, it will preserves the dimension of the subgroup. So, how do I compute the basis?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form